# Windows 10 Xbox games: "Let this app access your info?"

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-8-games

Every time I open *Asphalt 8: Airborne* on Windows 10 (natively a Win8 app -- an Xbox Live app, to be more precise), I get a popup message that says the following:

> Let this app access your info?
>     Asphalt 8: Airborne needs your permission to:
>     **Access and update your Xbox Live info**
>     You can change these application permissions at any time in your account settings.

... to which I always click No. I neither have an Xbox profile nor am I interested in setting up and using one. I just would like to be able to play this game and not see this message every time I want to run it. When I ran it on Windows 8.1, I was never asked (let alone pestered) to provide access to an Xbox Live profile. Is there a way I can suppress this message? Thank you immensely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably how they make money nowadays.
It wouldn't surprise me if giving away access to your xbox live account, includes giving away info about the linked gmail, which is either then cross referenced or just given away as well, giving away all the information there ever was to be had about you.

These games claim to ask for access to 'xbox live account information', but its already public! Worse yet, xbox live reads your hard drive and includes every single game installed on your computer, even standalone games that have their own launcher/updater!

Proof: https://xboxgamertag.com/search/Player493277943/

After this xbox game pass trial is over, I'm going straight back to steam. There's 0 reason to use xbox live when they just give away all your personal information without even asking you.

Remember, this is how they make money off of you, so I assume it's not possible to disable it, at least I'm not aware of that option.